# Flexbox responsive layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am playing around with flexbox and need a little help. I want a large square element to the left and a grid of four smaller elements, that equal the size of the first to the right.

So far I have this:

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex: 0 0 47%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:30px;padding-top:1px;" id="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    dhhrth rthrthrth rth rhrthrth
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container-inner">
    <div class="flex-item">
      yt e ert et e
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/DaveBatt83/pen/yVbGQG

I don't understand why the four smaller elements stack atop each other when the width of the screen is reduced, and I would also like to set a minimum width of the large one so that at certain breakpoints it takes up the full width. Is this possible

I want the first item to take up 47% of the width, then by adding a nested container i want to create two rows of two items at 47% within the nested container. The 47% is to create some spacing between them using space-between.

This all seems to work but if the screen size is reduced the two rows of two becomes a column of the 4 items.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the name of the nested flex-items for clarity. Most probably you were having trouble because your were missing `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item,
.flex-container-inner,
.flex-item-inner {
  flex: 0 0 47%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item,
.flex-item-inner {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-container-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:30px;padding-top:1px;" id="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    dhhrth rthrthrth rth rhrthrth
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container-inner">
    <div class="flex-item-inner">
      yt e ert et e
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-inner">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-inner">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-inner">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```